# Read file byte by byte using C

Tags: c, hex, byte

I am trying to read a file byte by byte then print it out using C, but the output doesn't match the display of the hex editor.

In hex editor the first 2 lines look like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0111 1111 1000 0000 0000
```

expected output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000001111111100000000000
```

but when my code outputs this:

```
00000000000000000000001111111100
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned char buffer[4900] = "";
    int y;

    y = 0;
    fp = fopen("tugasz.ksa", "rb");

    for (int x = 0; x < 4900; x++) {
        fread(buffer, 1, 4900, fp);
        printf("%x", buffer[x]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). And no, you're not reading your file "byte by byte".

Comment: Move `fread` above the loop. Make it `y = fread(...)` and then loop to `y`.

Comment: @Weather it give me more different output "1ddd3cc0"

Comment: @Weather wait i'll try it

Comment: Cannot reproduce, after making those changes it works as expected. Check `fp` after you open the file to make sure it really did open.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Is %x really the same 'hex' thing as your hex editor? I think you should try to use itoa or some other things to get the right output.

Comment: You're not checking that the file is opened successfully.  You're not checking the return value from `fread()`.  When you read, you attempt to read 4900 bytes at a go (not byte by byte as your question title implies).  You print one byte from each of the 4900 values you 'read'.  Use `getc()` to read bytes one at a time.  Or use `fread()` but heed the return value (it says how many bytes were read) and then loop over the values read. The outer loop should call `fread()` and capture and test the result — `size_t nbytes; while ((nbytes = fread(…)) > 0)`. An inner loop deals with `nbytes` of data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There a multiple problems in your code:

- You do not test for `fopen` failure, causing undefined behavior if the file does not exist or cannot be open.
- You are not reading the file *byte by byte*, instead you are reading blocks of 4900 bytes and just print one byte of each block.
- You probably hit the end of file very quickly, but you do not test for end of file, so the output may come from the same part of the file. A classic case of one bug hiding another bug.
- The conversion format `%x` outputs 1 or 2 characters per byte depending on the byte value. This is a problem is the file contents are `0x00`, `0x01`, `0x10` and `0x11`, which respectively produce `0`, `1`, `10` and `11`, hence the apparent misaligned input.
- For cleanliness, you should `fclose` the stream.
- From the data posted, it is unclear if the hex editor is displaying data in hexadecimal or binary format and whether the values are word based or byte based.

Here is a simpler approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int c, i, max;

    fp = fopen("tugasz.ksa", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0, max = 4900; i < max && (c = getc(fp)) != EOF; i++) {
        printf("%02x", c);
        if (i % 16 == 15)
            putchar('\n');  // 16 bytes per line
        else if (i % 2 == 1)
            putchar(' ');   // group bytes in pairs
    }
    if (i % 16 != 0)
        putchar('\n');  // output a newline if needed

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for(int x = 0; x<4900; x++) {
>    fread(buffer, 1, 4900, fp);
>    printf("%x", buffer[x]);
> }
> ```

In the first iteration of the loop, this will print only the first character in `buffer` at index 0.

In the second iteration, this will print the the second character in `buffer` at index 1.

So if your file is less than 4900 bytes, it prints only 1 character. The reason you get more output is because the loop doesn't break when you reach end of file. It's printing mostly garbage, not the actual file content.

Given the hex-decimal view of your input file, and the expectation that the output is all 0 and 1, it is unlikely that the source file is a collection of bytes consisting of 0 and 1. Instead, it likely contains bytes from 0 to 256, and each byte is a collection of 0 and 1 bits. Print it as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("tugasz.ksa", "rb");
    if(fp)
    {
        unsigned char buffer[4096];
        size_t sz;
        int line = 0;
        while ((sz = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            {
                //print the bits of the byte, at buffer[i]:
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    int mask = 1 << (7 - j);
                    int bit = buffer[i] & mask;
                    printf("%d", bit ? 1 : 0);
                }

                //add new line for every 4 byte
                line++;
                if((line % 4) == 0)
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If bytes are 0 and 1, then simply print it as `printf("%d", buffer[i])` or `printf("%02X", buffer[i])` for byte values:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("tugasz.ksa", "rb");
    if(fp)
    {
        unsigned char buffer[4096];
        size_t sz;
        while((sz = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
                printf("%d", buffer[i]);
                //or use "%02X" instead, for printing the byte values:
                //printf("%02X ", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```